# ¿Cómo hacer un anillo de procesos en Linux sin utilizar ficheros, tuberías u otros mecanismos externos sólo señales?

Tags: linux, proceso

Hola buenas quería saber como se podría hacer un anillo de procesos en Linux utilizando solamente señales ,sin utilizar tuberías o algo por el estilo, he intentado de todas las formas pero no consigo hacerlo sin aplicar mecanismos externos para transmitir información entre procesos. Cualquier ayuda es buena gracias.

Aquí creo un proceso padre con 5 hijos pero no sé cómo hacer para que esos 5 hijos entren en un anillo de procesos circular.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main (int argc, char** argv) {      
    int status, i, j, valor;


    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        

            valor = fork();             
            
            if (valor==0) { 
                
                pids[i] = getpid();
                        
                break;
            }
            else if (valor==-1) {           
                perror("ERROR al hacer fork()");
                exit(1);
                break;
            }
        }       

        if (valor==0){ 
            printf("Soy el hijo:%d\n", getpid());
            
            }

        else {                  
            
            printf("Soy el padre:%d\n", getpid());

        }

    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: y tus ejemplos? qué has intentado?

Comment: Los intentos que he hecho están totalmente mal por eso no adjunto código. He intentado para los procesos para que esperen a que esté creado el último proceso del anillo y que se reanuden luego pero no sale como esperaba, además no tengo un padre con varios hijos si no que realiza varias veces el programa creando varios padres

Comment: este sitio no va de "necesito hacer x cosa" háganlo por mí. si muestras tus ejemplos, podemos ayudarte a ver qué está saliendo mal, o porqué no funciona.

Comment: Vale perdona, he añadido el código para cualquier ayuda

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El titulo en mayusculas es porque estas gritando?? ;)